# R Error Genetic Programming Implementation

Tags: r, genetic-programming

So I am brand new to R. I started learning it yesterday, because there's some data that is being very resistant to automatically importing into Mathematica and Python. I'm building a few machine learning techniques to do analysis on the data that I can now import with R. This is a genetic programming implementation that when finished should do symbolic regression on some data. (I have yet to create the mutation or crossover operators, build a legit function list, etc). I get two errors when I run the script:

> ```
> > Error: attempt to apply non-function
> > print(bestDude)
> > Error in print(bestDude) : object 'bestDude' not found
> ```

This is my code:

```
library("datasets")

#Allows me to map a name to each element in a numerical list.
makeStrName<-function(listOfItems)
{
  for(i in 1:length(listOfItems))
  {
        names(listOfItems)[i]=paste("x",i,sep="")
  }
  return(listOfItems)
}

#Allows me to replace each random number in a vector with the corresponding 
#function in a list of functions.

mapFuncList<-function(funcList,rndNumVector)
{
  for(i in 1:length(funcList))
  {
    replace(rndNumVector, rndNumVector==i,funcList[[i]])
  }
  return(rndNumVector)
}

#Will generate a random function from the list of functions and a random sample.
generateOrganism<-function(inputLen,inputSeed, functions)
{
  set.seed(inputSeed)
  rnd<-sample(1:length(functions),inputLen,replace=T)
  Org<-mapFuncList(functions,rnd)
  return(Org)
}

#Will generate a series of "Organisms"
genPopulation<-function(popSize,initialSeed,initialSize,functions)
{
  population<-list("null")
  for(i in 2:popSize)
  {
    population <- c(population,generateOrganism(initialSize,initialSeed, functions))
    initialSeed <- initialSeed+1
  }
  populationWithNames<-makeStrName(population)
  return(populationWithNames)
}

#Turns the population of functions (which are actually strings in "") into
#actual functions. (i.e. changes the mode of the list from string to function).

populationFuncList<-function(Population)
{
  Population[[1]]<-"x"
  funCreator<-function(snippet)
    txt=snippet
  function(x)
  {
    exprs <- parse(text = txt)
    eval(exprs) 
  }
  listOfFunctions <- lapply(setNames(Population,names(Population)),function(x){funCreator(x)})
  return(listOfFunctions)
}

#Applies a fitness function to the population. Puts the best organism in
#the hallOfFame.
evalPopulation<-function(populationFuncList, inputData,outputData)
{   
  #rmse <- sqrt( mean( (sim - obs)^2))

  hallOfFame<-list(1000000000)
  for(i in 1:length(populationFuncList))
  {
        total<-list()
        for(z in 1:length(inputData))
        {
          total<-c(total,(abs(populationFuncList[[i]](inputData[[z]])-outputData[[z]])))
        }
        rmse<-sqrt(mean(total*total))
                   if(rmse<hallOfFame[[1]]) {hallOfFame[[1]]<-rmse}
  }
  return(hallOfFame)
}

#Function list, input data, output data (data to fit to)
funcs<-list("x","log(x)","sin(x)","cos(x)","tan(x)")
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)

#Function calls
POpulation<-genPopulation(4,1,1,funcs)
POpulationFuncList<-populationFuncList(POpulation)
bestDude<-evalPopulation(POpulationFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput)
print(bestDude)
```

The code is now working thanks to Hack-R's suggestions. So here's the finalized code in case someone else runs into a similar trouble.

```
library("datasets")

#Allows me to map a name to each element in a numerical list.
makeStrName<-function(listOfItems)
{
  for(i in 1:length(listOfItems))
  {
    names(listOfItems)[i]=paste("x",i,sep="")
  }
  return(listOfItems)
}

#Allows me to replace each random number in a vector with the corresponding 
#function in a list of functions.

mapFuncList<-function(funcList,rndNumVector)
{
  for(i in 1:length(funcList))
  {
    rndNumVector[rndNumVector==i]<-funcList[i]
  }
  return(rndNumVector)
}

#Will generate a random function from the list of functions and a random sample.
generateOrganism<-function(inputLen,inputSeed, functions)
{
  set.seed(inputSeed)
  rnd<-sample(1:length(functions),inputLen,replace=T)
  Org<-mapFuncList(functions,rnd)
  return(Org)
}

#Will generate a series of "Organisms"
genPopulation<-function(popSize,initialSeed,initialSize,functions)
{
  population<-list()
  for(i in 1:popSize)
  {
    population <- c(population,generateOrganism(initialSize,initialSeed,functions))
    initialSeed <- initialSeed+1
  }
  populationWithNames<-makeStrName(population)
  return(populationWithNames)
}

#Turns the population of functions (which are actually strings in "") into
#actual functions. (i.e. changes the mode of the list from string to function).

funCreator<-function(snippet)
{
  txt=snippet
  function(x)
  {
    exprs <- parse(text = txt)
    eval(exprs) 
  }
}

#Applies a fitness function to the population. Puts the best organism in
#the hallOfFame.
evalPopulation<-function(populationFuncList, inputData,outputData)
{   
  #rmse <- sqrt( mean( (sim - obs)^2))

  hallOfFame<-list(1000000000)
  for(i in 1:length(populationFuncList))
  {
    total<-vector(mode="numeric",length=length(inputData))
    for(z in 1:length(inputData))
    {
      total<-c(total,(abs(populationFuncList[[i]](inputData[[z]])-outputData[[z]])))
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(total*total))
    if(rmse<hallOfFame[[1]]) {hallOfFame[[1]]<-rmse}
  }
  return(hallOfFame)
}

#Function list, input data, output data (data to fit to)
funcs<-list("x","log(x)","sin(x)","cos(x)","tan(x)")
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)

#Function calls
POpulation<-genPopulation(4,1,1,funcs)
POpulationFuncList <- lapply(setNames(POpulation,names(POpulation)),function(x){funCreator(x)})

bestDude<-evalPopulation(POpulationFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput)
print(bestDude)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `evalPopulation` you're attempting to apply `populationFuncList[[i]]` as if it were a function, but when you pass in the argument `POpulationFuncList` to replace the variable `populationFuncList` it's not a function, it's a list.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do, so I'm not sure which way you want to fix this. If you meant to use a function you should change the name of the object you're referencing to the function and remove it as an argument or at least pass a function in as an argument instead of the list.

OTOH if you meant to use the list `POpulationFuncList` then you just shouldn't be applying it as if it were a function instead of a list.

On a side note, this probably would be more apparent if you didn't give them such similar names.

**Another potential problem** is that you seem have non-numeric results in one of your lists:

```
> populationFuncList(POpulation)
$x1
[1] "x"

$x2
[1] 2

$x3
[1] 1

$x4
[1] 1
```

You can't take the absolute value of the character "x", so I just wanted to make sure you're aware of this.

**A third problem** is that you're doing math on a non-numeric data typed object called `total`. You need to either change the type to numeric or index it appropriately.

Now it's impossible for me to know exactly which of an infinite number of possibilities you should choose to fix this, because I don't know the details of your use case. However, here is one possible solution which you should be able to adapt to the specifics of the use case:

```
library("datasets")

#Allows me to map a name to each element in a numerical list.
makeStrName<-function(listOfItems)
{
  for(i in 1:length(listOfItems))
  {
    names(listOfItems)[i]=paste("x",i,sep="")
  }
  return(listOfItems)
}

#Allows me to replace each random number in a vector with the corresponding 
#function in a list of functions.

mapFuncList<-function(funcList,rndNumVector)
{
  for(i in 1:length(funcList))
  {
    replace(rndNumVector, rndNumVector==i,funcList[[i]])
  }
  return(rndNumVector)
}

#Will generate a random function from the list of functions and a random sample.
generateOrganism<-function(inputLen,inputSeed, functions)
{
  set.seed(inputSeed)
  rnd<-sample(1:length(functions),inputLen,replace=T)
  Org<-mapFuncList(functions,rnd)
  return(Org)
}

#Will generate a series of "Organisms"
genPopulation<-function(popSize,initialSeed,initialSize,functions)
{
  population<-list("null")
  for(i in 2:popSize)
  {
    population <- c(population,generateOrganism(initialSize,initialSeed, functions))
    initialSeed <- initialSeed+1
  }
  populationWithNames<-makeStrName(population)
  return(populationWithNames)
}

#Turns the population of functions (which are actually strings in "") into
#actual functions. (i.e. changes the mode of the list from string to function).

populationFuncList<-function(Population)
{
  Population[[1]]<-"x"
  funCreator<-function(snippet)
    txt=snippet
  function(x)
  {
    exprs <- parse(text = txt)
    eval(exprs) 
  }
  listOfFunctions <- lapply(setNames(Population,names(Population)),function(x){funCreator(x)})
  return(listOfFunctions)
}

#Applies a fitness function to the population. Puts the best organism in
#the hallOfFame.
evalPopulation<-function(myList=myList, dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput)
{   
  #rmse <- sqrt( mean( (sim - obs)^2))

  hallOfFame<-list(1000000000)
  for(i in 1:length(populationFuncList))
  {
    total<-0
    for(z in 1:length(dataForInput))
    {
      total<-c(total,(abs(myList[[i]]+(dataForInput[[z]])-desiredFuncOutput[[z]])))
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(total*total))
    if(rmse<hallOfFame[[1]]) {hallOfFame[[1]]<-rmse}
  }
  return(hallOfFame)
}

#Function list, input data, output data (data to fit to)
funcs<-list("x","log(x)","sin(x)","cos(x)","tan(x)")
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)

#Function calls
POpulation<-genPopulation(4,1,1,funcs)
myList <-populationFuncList(POpulation)[2:4]
bestDude<-evalPopulation(myList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput)
print(bestDude)
[[1]]
[1] 1.825742
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. The way I'm using my list of functions is based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117223/create-a-list-of-functions-from-a-vector-of-characters The example I'm using is at the bottom. I'm pretty sure the way I'm using it is correct. The only thing I can think of is if returning the list of functions and then applying it in that way fails, or that using an iterator in a for loop to access different functions sequentially doesn't work. Are lists like C++ arrays in the sense that they must be of constant length?

Comment: The error does sound like it is a problem with how I'm using my function list. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't think of that.

Comment: You're welcome. But yours isn't a list of functions, it's just a list***. It contains 4 elements -- one string (`x`) and three numeric (2, 1, 1). That's why you got the error in your question and why the error goes away when you don't use the list as a function. To answer your other question lists don't have to be constant length. ***If you mean that your example is different from the actual code you're running in that your actual code has a list of functions, then you should update the code in your question as such so that we can see what went wrong.

Comment: Ohhh. I bet its a problem with my map function. The numbers in the list should have been converted to strings like "x" for the number 1, "log(x)" for the number 2, etc. That would break down the whole program. I didn't realize the list was still numeric. I'll try to fix that and get back to you.

Comment: Cool, that's probably the answer then. When you fix that (and the 1 or 2 other things I caught like the use of `total`) then the code should hopefully work. :)

Comment: The code is now working. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @NovicePolymath Glad to hear it!