# R GP Implementation Error

Tags: r, genetic-programming

So I am very new to R. I was having some trouble importing data with Mathematica, so I decided to make a switch since R is much better suited to analytics. I'm building a few machine learning techniques to do analysis on the data that I can now import. This is a genetic programming implementation that when finished should do symbolic regression on some data. Other than the errors, the script should be almost complete (I need to program the composition operator, make the division protected, and finish the list of base functions). I had a previous problem while programming the script that was resolved ([R Error Genetic Programming Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768064/r-error-genetic-programming-implementation)). I've been debugging the script for about a day and I'm all out of ideas.

My error message is:

```
Error in makeStrName(nextGen) : object 'nextGen' not found
> 
> #Print the string versions of the five functions with the lowest RMSE evolved.
> byRMSEList<-sortByRMSE(populationsBestTenStr)
Error: object 'totalTwo' not found
> for(i in 1:5)
+ {
+   byRMSEList[[i]]
+ }
Error: object 'byRMSEList' not found
```

Here is my script. I am currently using RStudio. Thanks for taking the time to help:

```
library("datasets")

operators<-list("+","*","-","/","o")
funcs<-list("x","log(x)","sin(x)","cos(x)","tan(x)")

#Allows me to map a name to each element in a numerical list.
makeStrName<-function(listOfItems)
{
  for(i in 1:length(listOfItems))
  {
    names(listOfItems)[i]=paste("x",i,sep="")
  }
  return(listOfItems)
}

#Allows me to replace each random number in a vector with the corresponding
#function in a list of functions.

mapFuncList<-function(funcList,rndNumVector)
{
  for(i in 1:length(funcList))
  {
    rndNumVector[rndNumVector==i]<-funcList[i]
  }
  return(rndNumVector)
}

#Will generate a random function from the list of functions and a random sample.
generateOrganism<-function(inputLen,inputSeed, funcList)
{
  set.seed(inputSeed)
  rnd<-sample(1:length(funcList),inputLen,replace=T)
  Org<-mapFuncList(funcList,rnd)
  return(Org)
}

#Will generate a series of "Organisms"
genPopulation<-function(popSize,initialSeed,initialSize,functions)
{
  population<-list()
  for(i in 1:popSize)
  {
    population <- c(population,generateOrganism(initialSize,initialSeed+i,functions))
  }
  populationWithNames<-makeStrName(population)
  return(populationWithNames)
}

#Turns the population of functions (which are actually strings in "") into
#actual functions. (i.e. changes the mode of the list from string to function).

funCreator<-function(snippet)
{
  txt=snippet
  function(x)
  {
    exprs <- parse(text = txt)
    eval(exprs)
  }
}

#Applies a fitness function to the population. Puts the best organism in
#the hallOfFame.
evalPopulation<-function(populationFuncList, inputData, outputData, populationStringList)
{
  #rmse <- sqrt( mean( (sim - obs)^2))
  for(i in 1:length(populationStringList))
  {
    stringFunc<-populationStringList[[i]]
    total<-list(mode="numeric",length=length(inputData))
    topTenPercentFunctionList<-list()
    topTenPercentRMSEList<-list()
    topTenPercentStringFunctionList<-list()
    tempFunc<-function(x){x}
    for(z in 1:length(inputData))
    {
      total<-c(total,(abs(populationFuncList[[i]](inputData[[z]])-outputData[[z]])))
      tempFunc<-populationFuncList[[i]]
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(total*total))
    topTenPercentVal<-length(populationFuncList)*0.1
    if(length(topTenPercentFunctionList)<topTenPercentVal||RMSE<min(topTenPercentRMSEList))
    {
      topTenPercentStringFunctionList<-c(topTenPercentStringFunctionList,stringFunc)
      topTenPercentRMSEList<-c(topTenPercentRMSEList, rmse)
      topTenPercentFunctionList<-c(topTenPercentFunctionList, tempFunc)
    }
  }
  return(topTenPercentStringFunctionList)
}
#Get random operator
getRndOp<-function(seed)
{
  set.seed(seed)
  rndOpNum<-sample(1:length(operators),1,replace=T)
  operation<-operators[[rndOpNum]]
  return(operation)
}

#Mutation Operators

#This attaches a new appendage to an organism
endNodeMutation<-function(strFunc,seed)
{
  op<-getRndOp(seed)
  strFunc<-c(strFunc,op)
  newAppendage<-generateOrganism(1,seed+2,funcs)
  strFunc<-c(strFunc,newAppendage)
  return(strFunc)
}

#This is a mutation that occurs at a random locaiton in an organism
rndNodeMutation<-function(strFunc,seed,secondSeed)
{
  op<-getRndOp(seed)
  halfStrFunc<-((length(strFunc))/2)
  set.seed(seed)
  randomStart<-sample(1:halfStrFunc,1,replace=T)
  set.seed(secondSeed)
  randomEnd<-2*(sample(1:length(halfStrFunc),1,replace=T))
  strFuncUpdate<-substr(strFunc,randomStart,randomEnd)
  strFuncUpdate<-c(strFuncUpdate,op)
  newAppendage<-generateOrganism(1,seed+2,funcs)
  strFuncUpdate<-c(strFuncUpdate,newAppendage)
  return(strFuncUpdate)
}

#Crossover Operators

#Crossover operator that attaches otherStrFunc to strFunc at the endpoint of strFunc
crossoverConcatenationOperator<-function(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
{
  newStrFunc<-c(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
  return(newStrFunc)
}

#Crossover Operation that starts and ends at random points in the concatenation
randomCrossoverOperator<-function(strFunc,otherStrFunc,seed,secondSeed)
{
  set.seed(seed)
  wholeLength<-(length(strFunc)+length(otherStrFunc))
  startRndNum<-sample(1:length(strFunc),1,replace=T)
  set.seed(secondSeed)
  endRndNum<-sample(length(strFunc):wholeLength,1,replace=T)
  concatenatedFunc<-c(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
  newFunc<-substr(concatenatedFunc,startRndNum,endRndNum)
  return(newFunc)
}
evolve<-function(strFuncList,tenPercentStrFuncList)
{
  #Detach the bottom ninety percent to the top ten percent
  evolveList<-substr(strFuncList,length(tenPercentStrFuncList),length(strFuncList))
  #Get sizes. Will use a random mutation, then random crossover, then
  #random mutation, then random crossover at percentages with 0.05,0.45,0.05,0.45
  #respectively
  size<-length(evolveList)
  mutateNum<-0.1*size
  crossoverNum<-0.9*size
  halfMutateNum<-0.05*size
  halfCrossoverNum<-0.45*size
  roundedMutateNum<-floor(mutateNum)
  roundedCrossoverNum<-floor(crossoverNum)
  roundedHalfMutateNum<-floor(halfMutateNum)
  roundedHalfCrossoverNum<-floor(halfCrossoverNum)

  #Calls the functions for those percentage of organisms in that order
  for(i in 1:roundedHalfMutateNum)
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndNodeMutation(evolveList[[i]],rndOne,rndTWo)
    evolveList[[i]]<-newFunc
  }
  for (i in roundedHalfMutateNum:(roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndCrossoverOperation(evolveList[[i]],evolveList[[i+1]],rndOne,rndTwo)
    firstSubstr<-substr(evolveList,1,i-1)
    secondSubstr<-substr(evolveLIst,i+2,length(evolveList))
    halfSubstr<-c(firstSubstr,newFunc)
    evolveList<-c(halfSubstr,secondSubstr)
  }
  for(i in (roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum):(roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndNodeMutation(evolveList[[i]],rndOne,rndTWo)
    evolveList[[i]]<-newFunc
  }
  for(i in (roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedMutateNum):(roundedCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndCrossoverOperation(evolveList[[i]],evolveList[[i+1]],rndOne,rndTwo)
    firstSubstr<-substr(evolveList,1,i-1)
    secondSubstr<-substr(evolveLIst,i+2,length(evolveList))
    halfSubstr<-c(firstSubstr,newFunc)
    evolveList<-c(halfSubstr,secondSubstr)
  }
}

#Calculates the root mean squared of the functions in a string list.
#Then sorts the list by RMSE.
sortByRMSE<-function(strL)
{
  for (z in 1:length(strL))
  {
    for(i in 1:length(strL))
    {
      nonStrFuncList<-lapply(strL,function(x){funCreator(x)})
      totalTwo<-c(totalTwo,(abs(nonStrFuncList[[z]](inputData[[i]])-outputData[[i]])))
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(totalTwo*totalTwo))
    strFuncsLists<-strL[order(sapply(strL, '[[', rmse))]
  }
  return(strFuncsLists)
}

#Data, Output Goal
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,4,9,16,25)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)

#Generate Initial Population
POpulation<-genPopulation(4,1,1,funcs)
POpulationFuncList <- lapply(setNames(POpulation,names(POpulation)),function(x){funCreator(x)})

#Get and save top ten percent in bestDudes
bestDudes<-evalPopulation(POpulationFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput,POpulation)
#Evolve the rest
NewBottomNinetyPercent<-evolve(POpulation,bestDudes)
#Concatenate the two to make a new generation
nextGen<-c(bestDudes,NewBottomNinetyPercent)

#Declare lists,
populationsBestTenStr<-list()
populationsFuncList<-list()

#Run ten generations.
for(i in 1:10)
{
  nextGen<-makeStrName(nextGen)
  populationsFuncList<-lapply(setNames(nextGen,names(nextGen)),function(x){funCreator(x)})
  populationsBestTenStr<-evalPopulation(populationsFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput,nextGen)
  nextGen<-evolve(populations,populationsBestTenStr)
}

#Print the string versions of the five functions with the lowest RMSE evolved.
byRMSEList<-sortByRMSE(populationsBestTenStr)
for(i in 1:5)
{
  byRMSEList[[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library("datasets")

operators<-list("+","*","-","/","o")
funcs<-list("x","log(x)","sin(x)","cos(x)","tan(x)")

# Fixed:
# evolveLIst inconsistently typed as evolveList
# rndCrossoverOperation inconsistently typed as randomCrossoverOperator
# rndTWo inconsistently typed as rndTwo
# broken substr
# broken condition leading to for(i in 1:0)
# misc. others

#Allows me to map a name to each element in a numerical list.
makeStrName<-function(listOfItems)
{
  for(i in 1:length(listOfItems))
  {
    names(listOfItems)[i]=paste("x",i,sep="")
  }
  return(listOfItems)
}

#Allows me to replace each random number in a vector with the corresponding
#function in a list of functions.

mapFuncList<-function(funcList,rndNumVector)
{
  for(i in 1:length(funcList))
  {
    rndNumVector[rndNumVector==i]<-funcList[i]
  }
  return(rndNumVector)
}

#Will generate a random function from the list of functions and a random sample.
generateOrganism<-function(inputLen,inputSeed, funcList)
{
  set.seed(inputSeed)
  rnd<-sample(1:length(funcList),inputLen,replace=T)
  Org<-mapFuncList(funcList,rnd)
  return(Org)
}

#Will generate a series of "Organisms"
genPopulation<-function(popSize,initialSeed,initialSize,functions)
{
  population<-list()
  for(i in 1:popSize)
  {
    population <- c(population,generateOrganism(initialSize,initialSeed+i,functions))
  }
  populationWithNames<-makeStrName(population)
  return(populationWithNames)
}

#Turns the population of functions (which are actually strings in "") into
#actual functions. (i.e. changes the mode of the list from string to function).

funCreator<-function(snippet)
{
  txt=snippet
  function(x)
  {
    exprs <- parse(text = txt)
    eval(exprs)
  }
}

#Applies a fitness function to the population. Puts the best organism in
#the hallOfFame.
evalPopulation<-function(populationFuncList=POpulationFuncList, inputData=dataForInput, outputData=desiredFuncOutput,
                         populationStringList=POpulation)
{
  #rmse <- sqrt( mean( (sim - obs)^2))
  for(i in 1:length(populationStringList))
  {
    stringFunc<-populationStringList[[i]]
    total<-as.numeric(length(inputData))
    topTenPercentFunctionList<-list()
    topTenPercentRMSEList<-list()
    topTenPercentStringFunctionList<-list()
    tempFunc<-function(x){x}
    for(z in 1:length(inputData))
    {
      total<-c(total,(abs(populationFuncList[[i]](inputData[[z]])-outputData[[z]])))
      tempFunc<-populationFuncList[[i]]
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(total^2))
    topTenPercentVal<-length(populationFuncList)*0.1
    if(length(topTenPercentFunctionList)<topTenPercentVal||RMSE<min(topTenPercentRMSEList))
    {
      topTenPercentStringFunctionList<-c(topTenPercentStringFunctionList,stringFunc)
      topTenPercentRMSEList<-c(topTenPercentRMSEList, rmse)
      topTenPercentFunctionList<-c(topTenPercentFunctionList, tempFunc)
    }
  }
  return(topTenPercentStringFunctionList)
}
#Get random operator
getRndOp<-function(seed)
{
  set.seed(seed)
  rndOpNum<-sample(1:length(operators),1,replace=T)
  operation<-operators[[rndOpNum]]
  return(operation)
}

#Mutation Operators

#This attaches a new appendage to an organism
endNodeMutation<-function(strFunc,seed)
{
  op<-getRndOp(seed)
  strFunc<-c(strFunc,op)
  newAppendage<-generateOrganism(1,seed+2,funcs)
  strFunc<-c(strFunc,newAppendage)
  return(strFunc)
}

#This is a mutation that occurs at a random locaiton in an organism
rndNodeMutation<-function(strFunc,seed,secondSeed)
{
  op<-getRndOp(seed)
  halfStrFunc<-((length(strFunc))/2)
  set.seed(seed)
  randomStart<-sample(1:halfStrFunc,1,replace=T)
  set.seed(secondSeed)
  randomEnd<-2*(sample(1:length(halfStrFunc),1,replace=T))
  strFuncUpdate<-substr(strFunc,randomStart,randomEnd)
  strFuncUpdate<-c(strFuncUpdate,op)
  newAppendage<-generateOrganism(1,seed+2,funcs)
  strFuncUpdate<-c(strFuncUpdate,newAppendage)
  return(strFuncUpdate)
}

#Crossover Operators

#Crossover operator that attaches otherStrFunc to strFunc at the endpoint of strFunc
crossoverConcatenationOperator<-function(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
{
  newStrFunc<-c(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
  return(newStrFunc)
}

#Crossover Operation that starts and ends at random points in the concatenation
rndCrossoverOperation<-function(strFunc,otherStrFunc,seed,secondSeed) # fixed function name
{
  set.seed(seed)
  wholeLength<-(length(strFunc)+length(otherStrFunc))
  startRndNum<-sample(1:length(strFunc),1,replace=T)
  set.seed(secondSeed)
  endRndNum<-sample(length(strFunc):wholeLength,1,replace=T)
  concatenatedFunc<-c(strFunc,otherStrFunc)
  newFunc<-substr(concatenatedFunc,startRndNum,endRndNum)
  return(newFunc)
}
evolve<-function(strFuncList=POpulation,tenPercentStrFuncList=bestDudes)
{
  #Detach the bottom ninety percent to the top ten percent
  evolveList<-strFuncList[!strFuncList %in% tenPercentStrFuncList] # fixed broken substring
  #Get sizes. Will use a random mutation, then random crossover, then
  #random mutation, then random crossover at percentages with 0.05,0.45,0.05,0.45
  #respectively
  size<-length(evolveList)
  mutateNum<-0.1*size
  crossoverNum<-0.9*size
  halfMutateNum<-0.05*size
  halfCrossoverNum<-0.45*size
  roundedMutateNum<-floor(mutateNum)
  roundedCrossoverNum<-floor(crossoverNum)
  roundedHalfMutateNum<-floor(halfMutateNum)
  roundedHalfCrossoverNum<-floor(halfCrossoverNum)

  #Calls the functions for those percentage of organisms in that order
  if(roundedHalfMutateNum < 1) roundedHalfMutateNum <- 1
  for(i in 1:roundedHalfMutateNum)
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndNodeMutation(evolveList[[i]],rndOne,rndTwo) # fixed case
    evolveList[[i]]<-newFunc
  }
  for (i in roundedHalfMutateNum:(roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndCrossoverOperation(evolveList[[i]],evolveList[[i+1]],rndOne,rndTwo)
    firstSubstr<-substr(evolveList,1,i-1)
    secondSubstr<-substr(evolveList,i+2,length(evolveList))
    halfSubstr<-c(firstSubstr,newFunc)
    evolveList<-c(halfSubstr,secondSubstr)
  }
  for(i in (roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum):(roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndNodeMutation(evolveList[[i]],rndOne,rndTwo)
    evolveList[[i]]<-newFunc
  }
  for(i in (roundedHalfCrossoverNum+roundedMutateNum):(roundedCrossoverNum+roundedHalfMutateNum))
  {
    set.seed(i)
    rndOne<-sample(0:1000,1,replace=T)
    set.seed(i+10000)
    rndTwo<-sample(0:10000,1,replace=T)
    newFunc<-rndCrossoverOperation(evolveList[[i]],evolveList[[i+1]],rndOne,rndTwo)
    firstSubstr<-substr(evolveList,1,i-1)
    secondSubstr<-substr(evolveList,i+2,length(evolveList))
    halfSubstr<-c(firstSubstr,newFunc)
    evolveList<-c(halfSubstr,secondSubstr)
  }
}

#Calculates the root mean squared of the functions in a string list.
#Then sorts the list by RMSE.
sortByRMSE<-function(strL)
{
  for (z in 1:length(strL))
  {
    for(i in 1:length(strL))
    {
      nonStrFuncList<-lapply(strL,function(x){funCreator(x)})
      totalTwo<-c(totalTwo,(abs(nonStrFuncList[[z]](inputData[[i]])-outputData[[i]])))
    }
    rmse<-sqrt(mean(totalTwo*totalTwo))
    strFuncsLists<-strL[order(sapply(strL, '[[', rmse))]
  }
  return(strFuncsLists)
}

#Data, Output Goal
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,4,9,16,25)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)

#Generate Initial Population
POpulation<-genPopulation(4,1,1,funcs)
POpulationFuncList <- lapply(setNames(POpulation,names(POpulation)),function(x){funCreator(x)})

#Get and save top ten percent in bestDudes
bestDudes<-evalPopulation(POpulationFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput,POpulation)
#Evolve the rest
NewBottomNinetyPercent<-evolve(POpulation,bestDudes)
#Concatenate the two to make a new generation
nextGen<-c(bestDudes,NewBottomNinetyPercent)

#Declare lists,
populationsBestTenStr<-list()
populationsFuncList<-list()

#Run ten generations.
for(i in 1:10)
{
  nextGen<-makeStrName(nextGen)
  populationsFuncList<-lapply(setNames(nextGen,names(nextGen)),function(x){funCreator(x)})
  populationsBestTenStr<-evalPopulation(populationsFuncList,dataForInput,desiredFuncOutput,nextGen)
  nextGen<-evolve(populations,populationsBestTenStr)
}

#Print the string versions of the five functions with the lowest RMSE evolved.
byRMSEList<-sortByRMSE(populationsBestTenStr)
for(i in 1:5)
{
  byRMSEList[[i]]
}
```

Comment: I do have that in my code. See "#Data, Output Goal
desiredFuncOutput<-list(1,4,9,16,25)
dataForInput<-list(1,2,3,4,5)" For some reason it didn't copy to yours. Fixed mapStrFunc, thanks for the tip

Comment: Its just above the call for evalPopulation in the code I posted.

Comment: @novice-polymath OK I fixed another bug and now it works through `evolve` but I don't know what you were trying to do with the `substr`. It seems to be truncating the `POpulation` values arbitrarily. I see the comment for that line but I don't really get it. Can you help me out? I have to go to a meeting but I'll come back to this later today.

Comment: @NovicePolymath was it just supposed to remove `bestDudes` from `POpulation`?

Comment: Yes. Basically the idea is to keep the top ten percent (bestDudes) the same, and then use crossover and mutation operators on the bottom ninety-percent. In the random mutation and random crossover functions, I'm using it to evolve the population while avoiding bloat. So it (ideally) picks random locations to change things and discards what is outside the start and end positions. Could I ask why my substr was broken, so I don't make the same mistake again? I looked over the changes and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @NovicePolymath The substring I was talking about was `evolveList<-substr(strFuncList,length(tenPercentStrFuncList),length(strFuncList))`. The objects I have being fed into it are `strFuncList=POpulation,tenPercentStrFuncList=bestDudes`. So it was subsetting each element of `POpulation` to only keep characters `1:4` in my example run. Unless something got messed up `POpulation` has elements like `sin(x)`. So the substr turned that element into `sin(` for example, which didn't look right to me.