# Define list of R functions

Tags: r, function, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to define a list of functions in a loop, like so:

```
rr <- list(); ss <- list(list(1,2),list(3,4))

for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
  A <- ss[[i]][1]
  B <- ss[[i]][2]
  print(paste("A, B:", A, ",", B))
  rr[[i]] <- function () { force(B); B }
}
```

The `print` statement gives:

```
[1] "A, B: 1 , 2"
[1] "A, B: 3 , 4"
```

...which is what I want! But, when I try to use the functions, I get the wrong answer (`A` and `B` are lazily evaluated and wait until the function is actually called to get their values, I think):

```
> environment(rr[[1]])$A
[[1]]
[1] 3

> rr[[1]]()
[[1]]
[1] 4

> environment(rr[[2]])$A
[[1]]
[1] 3

> rr[[2]]()
[[1]]
[1] 4
```

How can I rewrite the above `for` loop so that each function `rr[[i]]` has its own *internal* set of parameters, which won't be modified by later `rr[[n > i]]` function definitions?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want both `A` and `B` to be internal parameters of the functions? The above code only makes `B` in the functions.

Comment: No I wanted to dynamically define functions within a loop but I was running into errors because the parameters are global, and when the last function is defined, all of the previous functions are affected by the redefinition of that global variable within their environment. I figured out what I wanted to do, anyway -- see below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `fortunes::fortune(106)`.  There's certainly a better way to do this.

One way is to make a "function factory" to capture the values.  For example,

```
make_fn <- function(A, B) {
  force(A)
  force(B)
  function(x) A <= x & x <= B  
}
```

Then your loop would be

```
for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
  A <- ss[[i]][1]
  B <- ss[[i]][2]
  print(paste("A, B:", A, ",", B))
  rr[[i]] <- make_fn(A, B)
}
```

Edited to add response to comment:  The difference here with `force()` is as follows:  `force()` applies to promises, i.e. arguments of functions.  In your example, `B` was never an argument to any function, so it was never a promise, and `force(B)` does nothing except return its value.  In my answer, `A` and `B` are arguments to `make_fn`, so when it is evaluated they are promises, and `force()` causes their expressions to be evaluated and their values to be fixed.

Comment: This is a much better solution than my answer. Not sure why `force` works in the external function `make_fn` and not within the definition of `rr[[i]]` itself, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** my solution below might help someone so I'll leave it here for posterity, but [user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580339/2925434) is a much better solution for my use-case.

---

Aha! I figured it out, with some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144097/2925434):

```
rr <- list(); ss <- list(list(1,2),list(3,4))

for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
  rr[[i]] <- function(x){}
  body(rr[[i]]) <- parse(text={
    paste("(", ss[[i]][[1]], "<= x) && (x <=", ss[[i]][[2]], ")")
  })
}

> rr[[1]](1.5) # within range [1,2]
[1] TRUE
> rr[[1]](2.5)
[1] FALSE

> rr[[2]](3.5) # within range [3,4]
[1] TRUE
> rr[[2]](4.5)
[1] FALSE
```